# Ionic 4 File upload going to previous page

Tags: android, ios, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

Working on a Project with IONIC 4 and facing Strange Behavior while upload an image / Photo to remote server using file transfer plugin.

After uploading an Image application going to previous page on both cases(success / fail).

```
import { Camera, CameraOptions } from '@ionic-native/camera/ngx';
import { FileTransfer, FileUploadOptions, FileTransferObject } from '@ionic-native/file-transfer/ngx';
import { File } from '@ionic-native/file/ngx';
     constructor{
        private camera: Camera,
        private transfer: FileTransfer,
        private file: File,
      ) {
    }
    takePhoto(){
      const options: CameraOptions = {
        quality: 50,
        destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
        mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
        sourceType: this.camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
        correctOrientation: true
      }

      this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
       // imageData is either a base64 encoded string or a file URI
       // If it's base64 (DATA_URL):
       this.uploadPhoto(imageData);
      }, (err) => {
       // Handle error
      });
    }
    uploadPhoto(path){
       const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
           let options: FileUploadOptions = {
              fileKey: 'file',
              fileName: '.png',
              chunkedMode: false,
              //mimeType: "image/jpeg",
           }
           fileTransfer.upload(path, 'my remote server url', options)
              .then((data) => {
               console.log(JSON.parse(data.response));
               let res = JSON.parse(data.response);
               if (res.status == 1) {
                  this.general.presentToast('Event Image Updated');
               }      
            }, (err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });
        }
```

After Uploading image application going to previous page unexpectedly.
Plugins Details:

```
cordova-plugin-camera 4.1.0 "Camera"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.2 "File"
cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.7.1 "File Transfer"

Ionic:


   Ionic CLI                     : 5.2.1 (C:\Users\ammar\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.6.2
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.13.9
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1

Cordova:

   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : android 8.0.0
   Cordova Plugins   : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 4.1.1, (and 13 other plugins)

Utility:

   cordova-res : 0.5.1
   native-run  : 0.2.7

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (C:\Users\ammar\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk)
   NodeJS            : v10.15.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.11.3
   OS                : Windows 10
```

Edit:
New Information added.

Comment: can you share more of that page code? does template user routers link etc?

Comment: Yes, i am using Angular Router. But not using it on this page.

Comment: so can you share more of your code? it is impossible to help without that context. The plugin itself does not govern your pages navigation so it is something else that does it...

Comment: @SergeyRudenko Thats the real problem i am facing. why this is happening. i have nothing on this page. except camera and file upload.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved:

What Actually happened:

I have Network Plugin to check if Connection is lost and Opening Camera was causing this whenever application comes from camera the Network Plugin invokes and routes application to the previous page. so i had to change Network logic and it soled my issue. 
Now, i noticed another thing when when you open camera with network plugin installed it will check for internet connection. Why?